# iOS siri shortcuts Swift

Tags: ios, swift, siri

I am learning swift currently for our radio station, and I have noticed that a rival station as been able to set up a siri shortcut that allows people to say "Hey Siri play (station name)" and Siri will open the app and start playing said station.

I am wondering how that could be done with Swift?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sirikit/overview/siri-shortcuts/

Comment: @DanielStorm thanks, but I was asking more an example like how to set up siri shoutcuts in swift

Comment: @RussellHarrower you can follow this example https://www.raywenderlich.com/600-sirikit-tutorial-for-ios

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of `Siri's intent`. You will have to create a *Siri intent definition file* using Xcode.

**Sample Intent Definition for PlayGame:**

[image]

In the above example, I have created simple intent for play games. I have added category as `Do`, There are many categories you can choose from. You can also pass the parameter through intent, just like I have used `game name` you can add `radio station name` there.

You can also add this particular intent for the Siri suggestion feature.

**Handling Siri Intent event:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    if userActivity.activityType == "PlayGameIntent" {
        print(userActivity.userInfo ?? "")
    }

    return true
}
```

> Note: You will have to donate this intent to the iOS to handle, you
>   can do it by following way:

```
let intent = PlayGameIntent()
intent.gameName = "PUBG"

let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
interaction.donate { (error) in
    print(error ?? "error")
}
```

Comment: What if your not developing a game, as we can't use PlayGame Kit.

Comment: @RussellHarrower you can add it for normal app, it's not specific to Game.

Comment: @RussellHarrower PlayGame is just intent name, you can name it whatever you want. basically this intent is used to add shortcuts and add your app's content into suggestion depend upon user's behaviour.

Comment: Hi Jarvis I worked out that I put the func app... in the AppDelegate.swift but where do I place the let intent = PlayGameIntent()?

Comment: In whichever view controller you want to donate intent to the Siri.

Comment: I put them in my firstViewController and they gave errors, could you post a sample viewcontroller with that code so I know  where to place it. I tried ViewDidLoad